# implementing matrix addition in c

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm currently learning how to implementing threads and matrix in c right now and having trouble implementing a function that performs matrix addition with two threads. The code below if the function that I'm currently working on right now, as well as the test file used to test my implementation. The program takes the number of rows and columns from the command line, fills two matrices with random numbers, and compares the result of addMatrix() and addMatrix thread() and if no argument is specified, the program works on matrices of size 6 × 6. I keep getting an incorrect answer as well as a segmentation fault- core dump (./test-madd element[0][0] 2978345935.000000  0.000000. Results do not match.) and isn't exactly sure why? I'm pretty new to threads, so I honestly have no idea where I'm going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "matrix.h"

#define     NUM_THREADS     2

typedef struct {
    unsigned int id;
    TMatrix *m, *n, *t;
} thread_arg_t;

/* the main function of threads */
static void * thread_main(void * p_arg)
{
 
    thread_arg_t *arg = (thread_arg_t *)p_arg;
    unsigned int id = arg ->id;
    unsigned int start = id * (arg -> m -> nrows / NUM_THREADS);
    unsigned int end = (id + 1) * (arg -> m -> nrows / NUM_THREADS);

    unsigned int i = start;

    while (i == start && i < end) {
        unsigned int j = 0;
        while (j == 0 && j < arg->m->ncols) {
            arg->t->data[i][j] = arg->m->data[i][j] + arg->n->data[i][j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* Return the sum of two matrices. The result is in a newly creaed matrix. 
 *
 * If a pthread function fails, report error and exit. 
 * Return NULL if something else is wrong.
 *
 * Similar to addMatrix, but this function uses 2 threads.
 */
TMatrix * addMatrix_thread(TMatrix *m, TMatrix *n)
{
    if (    m == NULL || n == NULL
         || m->nrows != n->nrows || m->ncols != n->ncols )
        return NULL;

    TMatrix * t = newMatrix(m->nrows, m->ncols);
    if (t == NULL)
        return t;

    thread_arg_t args[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(i < NUM_THREADS){
        args[i].id = i;
        args[i].m = m;
        args[i].n = n;
        args[i].t = t;
        i++;
    }
    if(pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_main, &args[i]) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(i < NUM_THREADS){
        if(pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    return t;
}
```

here are my test-cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "matrix.h"

/* timing functions */
void    stopwatch_start();
double  stopwatch_read();

#define     DEFAULT_NROWS    6
#define     DEFAULT_NCOLS    6

static void check_pointer(void *p, char *s)
{
    if (p)
       return; 
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: Pointer is NULL.\n", s ? s : "");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int     nrows = DEFAULT_NROWS;
    int     ncols = DEFAULT_NCOLS;
    int     show_time = 0;
    int     count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strncmp(argv[i], "-t", 2) == 0) {
            show_time = atoi(&argv[i][2]);
            if (show_time <= 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Number of runs must be a positive integer: %s\n", &argv[i][2]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        } else if (isdigit(argv[i][0]) && count < 2) { 
            if (count == 0)
                nrows = atoi(argv[i]);
            else if (count == 1)
                ncols= atoi(argv[i]);
            count ++;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [nrows [ncols]] [-t]\n"
                            "<nrows> : number of rows. Default value is %d.\n"
                            "<ncols> : number of columns. Default value is %d.\n"
                            "-t      : show execution time.\n"
                            , argv[0], DEFAULT_NROWS, DEFAULT_NCOLS);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if (! (nrows > 0 && ncols > 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Both nrows and ncols must be positive integers: nrows=%d ncols=%d\n", nrows, ncols);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    double  time1, time2;

    TMatrix *m, *n;

    m = newMatrix(nrows, ncols);
    check_pointer(m, "m");
    n = newMatrix(nrows, ncols);
    check_pointer(n, "n");

    fillMatrix(m);
    fillMatrix(n);

    TMatrix *t1, *t2;
    stopwatch_start();
    t1 = addMatrix(m, n);
    check_pointer(t1, "t1");
    for (int i = 1; i < show_time; i ++) {
        freeMatrix(t1);
        t1 = addMatrix(m, n);
        check_pointer(t1, "t1");
    }
    time1 = stopwatch_read();
    
    stopwatch_start();
    t2 = addMatrix_thread(m, n);
    check_pointer(t2, "t2");
    for (int i = 1; i < show_time; i ++) {
        freeMatrix(t2);
        t2 = addMatrix_thread(m, n);
        check_pointer(t2, "t2");
    }
    time2 = stopwatch_read();

    int     r = compareMatrix(t1, t2);

    freeMatrix(m);
    freeMatrix(n);
    freeMatrix(t1);
    freeMatrix(t2);

    if (r) {
        printf("%s\n", "Results do not match.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", "Good work!");
    }

    if (show_time) {
        double speedup = 0;
        // only computes speedup if time2 is longer than 1ms
        if (time2 > 0.001) {
            speedup = time1/time2;
        }
        time1 /= show_time;
        time2 /= show_time;
        printf("num_runs=%d time1=%.4f time2=%.4f speedup=%.4f\n", show_time, time1, time2, speedup);
    }
    return 0;
}

/*********** Implementation of a timer ****************/
#define     MAX_RUN_TIME    1000000

#define     TIMER_TYPE  ITIMER_REAL
// #define      TIMER_TYPE  ITIMER_PROF

// start a stop watch, using system timer
void stopwatch_start()
{
    struct itimerval pval;

    /* set the timer*/
    pval.it_value.tv_sec = MAX_RUN_TIME;
    pval.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    /* No repeating */
    pval.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;     
    pval.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    if (setitimer(TIMER_TYPE, &pval, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: setitimer() failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/* Returns the number of seconds since last call to start_timer() 
 * The meaning of seconds depends on the timer type.
 * */
double stopwatch_read()
{
    struct itimerval val;
    long secs, usecs;
    double temp;

    if (getitimer(TIMER_TYPE, &val)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: getitimer() failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    secs = MAX_RUN_TIME - val.it_value.tv_sec - 1;
    usecs = 1000000 - val.it_value.tv_usec;

    temp = (double) secs + ((double) usecs/1000000.0);

    return (temp > 0 ? temp : 0.0 );
}
```

I've tired a different implementations where I changed the conditions of the while loops as shown below. I've also tried changing the while loops into for loops but that didn't work either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "matrix.h"

#define     NUM_THREADS     2

typedef struct {
    unsigned int id;
    TMatrix *m, *n, *t;
} thread_arg_t;

/* the main function of threads */
static void * thread_main(void * p_arg)
{
    thread_arg_t *arg_t = p_arg;
    int rows = arg_t ->n ->nrows;
    int cols = arg_t ->m ->ncols;
    TMatrix * t = arg_t -> t;
    TMatrix * m = arg_t -> m;
    TMatrix * n = arg_t -> n;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < rows){
        int j = 0;
        while(j < cols){
            if(i % 2 == arg_t ->id){
                t ->data[i][j] = m ->data[i][j] + n ->data[i][j]
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

/* Return the sum of two matrices. The result is in a newly creaed matrix. 
 *
 * If a pthread function fails, report error and exit. 
 * Return NULL if something else is wrong.
 *
 * Similar to addMatrix, but this function uses 2 threads.
 */
TMatrix * addMatrix_thread(TMatrix *m, TMatrix *n)
{
    if (    m == NULL || n == NULL
         || m->nrows != n->nrows || m->ncols != n->ncols )
        return NULL;

    TMatrix * t = newMatrix(m->nrows, m->ncols);
    if (t == NULL)
        return t;

    thread_arg_t args[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
        args[i].id = i;
        args[i].m = m;
        args[i].n = n;
        args[i].t = t;
        rc = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, thread_main, &id[i]);
        if(rc){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    
    for(int j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; j++) {
        pthread_join(threads[j], NULL);
        if(rc){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Debuggers are great tools for finding, you know, bugs.

Comment: Also, if you need debugging help. Make sure that you provide code that we can compile and run. Read about creating a [mre].